# Não consigo compilar glfw com um makefile

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile

Olá, uns dias atrás me senti na vontade de aprender opengl, e descobri o glfw e o glad. Decidi usá-los para fazer um joguinho.

A maioria dos tutoriais de hoje em dia só falam sobre como usá-los no Visual Studio, porém não quero usá-lo pois meu computador não é muito potente e o Visual Studio trava muito e é muito ineficiente na hora de usar, o que acaba com a produtividade.

Então eu resolvi tentar criar um Makefile, como nunca mexi com isso tive que me desafiar a criar o meu primeiro.

Aqui segue o código do Makefile:

```
INCLUDE = -ILibrary/include
LIB = -LLibrary/lib

OBJ = main.o glad.o

CFLAGS = -g -Wall

CFLAGS += $(INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS += $(LIB)

game: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o game.exe $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll

main.o: src/main.cpp
    g++ -c src/main.cpp $(INCLUDE) $(LIB) -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll

glad.o: Library/include/glad/glad.c Library/include/glad/glad.h
    g++ -c $(INCLUDE)glad/glad.c
```

Por algum motivo que eu ainda não sei o Makefile não funfa e acusa o seguinte erro:

```
g++ -c src/main.cpp -ILibrary/include -LLibrary/lib -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll
g++ -o game.exe main.o glad.o -g -Wall -ILibrary/include -LLibrary/lib -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:12: game] Error 1
```

Segue o meu código c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Erro";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, estarei grato.

Obs.: Como este é meu primeiro Makefile, qualquer crítica perante a ele será bem-vinda.

Comment: você está usando o mingw para rodar o makefile?

Comment: glfw é distribúido com um makefile complexo e completo. Instale CMake na sua máquina. CMakeLists.txt é o arquivo equivalente a um makefile. E no Linux vai gerar mesmo um makefile para compilar. No Windows precisa ver o "alvo" da geração, usando acho cmake -G

Comment: olá pessoal, estava fora do SO por um tempo e acabei conseguindo resolver o problema mesmo sozinho, obrigado a todos que tentaram colaborar